# Datastore doesn't save namespaceId in Array type column

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I am using google app engine datastore and I am saving the list of one entity keys in other entity with Array datatype. Some of the keys doesn't have the namespaceId. May I know the reason for this.

The Array looks like this

```
[{"partitionId":{"projectId":"-----","namespaceId":"-----"},"path":[{"kind":"Test","id":"1452455214555"}]}]
```

The above is correct one and it has namespaceId.

I have observed some of the things are like below

```
[{"partitionId":{"projectId":"-----"},"path":[{"kind":"Test","id":"1452455214555"}]}]
```

In the above one namespaceId is missing.

Can anybody help me to list out the issue.

Comment: Can you post sample code that reproduces this issue (also, which client library/version are you using)?

Comment: Below is our code to save the related contacts of a deal.

/**
 * Contact ids of related contacts for a deal.
 */
 @NotSaved
  private List<String> contact_ids = new ArrayList<String>();

    /**
     * Related contact objects fetched using contact ids.
     */
    private List<Key<Contact>> related_contacts = new ArrayList<Key<Contact>>();

Above two are datastore entity columns.

Comment: This is the if block written in save method of a deal.

if (contact_ids != null)
        {
            for (String contact_id : this.contact_ids)
            {
                this.related_contacts.add(new Key<Contact>(Contact.class, Long.parseLong(contact_id)));
            }

        }

Find the below datastore column properties snaggy with correct and wrong values.

Correct: https://snag.gy/oiszCZ.jpg
Wrong: https://snag.gy/v9pc8H.jpg